# バックグラウンドから戻るとimageの名前を忘れている

Tags: ios, swift

質問いたします。
UIImageViewに配列内のイメージを表示させています。
配列にはもともと持たせたイメージのほか、カメラから得たイメージも格納しています。
テーブルからの詳細画面viewのとき、ImageViewがもともと持たせたイメージを表示する場合、タイマーを使ってImageViewにアニメーションさせています。その際、イメージの名前を参照します。
さてホームボタンを押してアプリから一時離れ、戻ってくると、アニメーションが動かなくなります。
NSNotificationCenterを使うことで対処しようと試みました。timerは動くことを確認しましたが、イメージの名前を指定するとアニメーションしなくなります。
問題はどこでしょうか。初心者で恐縮ですが、どなたかご教授願います。

Comment: ご指導ありがとうございました。
ご指摘通り、プログラムの変更で解決しました。
原因はtimerではなく、imageの名前の参照でした。
具体的には、NSDataに変換して名前を比較するとうまくいきました。
またよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> テーブルからの詳細画面viewのとき、ImageViewがもともと持たせたイメージを表示する場合、タイマーを使ってImageViewにアニメーションさせています。その際、イメージの名前を参照します。

`UIImageView`は、タイマーを使わなくても、単独でアニメーションします。なので、あなたが直面している問題の、原因が解明しなくても、プログラムそのものを変更することで、問題を解決する可能性があります。

`UIImageView`の**アニメーションに関するリファレンス**

- `animationImages`　プロパティ。UIImageの配列。要素の順番でアニメーションする。
- `animationDuration`　プロパティ。アニメーションの間隔。秒単位。
- `animationRepeatCount`　プロパティ。アニメーションをくり返す回数。0を指定すると、エンドレスでくり返す。
- `startAnimating()`　メソッド。アニメーションを開始する。
- `stopAnimating()`　メソッド。アニメーションを停止する。
- `isAnimating()`　メソッド。アニメーション中だとtrueを返し、停止しているとfalseを返す。`startAnimating()`を重複して呼び出すと、挙動がおかしくなるので、`startAnimating()`、`stopAnimating()`を呼ぶ前に、アニメーション中かどうか、確認するために使うといいでしょう。